# how install packet in virtualbox by vagrant and pycharm?

Tags: python-2.7, vagrant, virtualbox, pycharm

i have a problem:
 I use virtualbox, vagrant and pycharm to create environment code

Then install vagrant,pycharm and virtualbox on win 8 64bit, i begin create a project and all ok

But i check version python on machine virtual(on virtualbox, i use centos6.4), version python is 2.6.3,i need python 2.7 for my project

Then i install python 2.7 change python2.6, all completed and success

But when i create other project use environment that i install python 2.7 but version python is python 2.6

I want all my project will run on the virtualbox in the future via Vagrant which always runs on Python 2.7. What should i do?

project new

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Tue Jul  1 14:45:18 2014 from 10.0.2.2
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 21 2013, 23:54:59)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

project old

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jul  1 2014, 10:42:45)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you like to use a centos 6.4 box but with a non-standard python version for all your projects? In this case you may have to [provision](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html) your box using a custom [shell script](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) that will handle the python upgrade process each time a centos 6.4 box is used.

Comment: yes, i want use a box that i upgrade for all my project

Comment: now i use box CentOS-6.4-i386-v20131103.box, it install python 2.6 is python defaul